# How do I get the equation for the locus of points at equal distance from $(1, 1)$ and $(-2, 2)$?

Tags: geometry, locus

> What does the equation of the locus of the points of the plane $P(x,y)$ whose distance from point $A(1,1)$ is equal to its distance from point $B(2,-2)$ correspond to?

The answer is $2x-6y-6=0$, but I can't figure out how to get there. As shown in the image, I tried to use the circumference equation, but it seems that it's much simpler.
I also can't figure out how this is represented in the plane $P(x,y)$.

Attached an image; it's in spanish.

[image: Here's the image but in spanish]

Comment: If the distances are equal so are their squares. Set up the equation expressing this fact and multiply out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p = $ distance from $(x, y)$ to $(1, 1)$ and $q =$ distance from $(x, y)$ to $(2, -2)$.

It follows from the Pythagorean theorem that $p^2 = (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2$ and $q^2 = (x-2)^2 + (y+2)^2$.

Hence, we have

$$p = q$$
$$\implies p^2 = q^2$$
$$\implies (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 = (x-2)^2 + (y+2)^2$$
$$\implies x^2 - 2x + 1 - x^2 + 4x - 4 = y^2 + 4y + 4 - y^2 + 2y - 1$$
$$\implies 2x - 3 = 6y + 3$$
$$\implies \fbox{$2x - 6y - 6 = 0$}$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Consider the direction $v = B - A = (2,-2) - (1,1) = (1,-3)$ and the midpoint $M = (3/2,-1/2)$.

Hence the perpendicular direction to $v$ is parallel to $w = (-3,1)$, for example.

Hence the locus is given by the following line (why?):
\begin{align*}
(x,y) & = M + tw\\\\
& = (3/2,-1/2) + t(-3,1)\\\\
& = (3/2 - 3t,-1/2 + t)
\end{align*}

then eliminate the variable $t$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes! Thanks for the help.